# Why is gedit so laggy when editing through FTP?

Tags: gedit, ftp

I use gedit to edit files on my Media Temple server, but it's so laggy. Other editors I've used don't have this problem.

Saving takes a long time, and gedit usually freezes up for a bit during this. Navigating through a file is also slow and problematic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it helps I use GoDaddy Hosting and work with some people in a serverloft dedicated server. In both I get good connections and bad connections depending the time of day or if I am sharing the connection with someone. If My ISP lines are saturated or if somebody else is sharing the same connection as me can lag when trying not only to find the file in the ftp site but also opening and editing it. Even saving it takes a lot when on peek hours.

I am using the default way of accessing the ftp site which is the nautilus "Connect to server" option. After that I double click a PHP or JS file to open it with gedit and start working on it.

If nobody else is sharing I tend to have good timing. Even better in night when there is less ISP users and my connections makes the ftp feel like is right beside me.

But anyhow, there are variables between connection sharing, isp speed and all the hops between there to media temple. I also gotta say that even though media temple has pretty good reviews and very nice service I did not find them better than lets say godaddy when it came to how good the connection is made. Used them for 2 years before going to godaddy and have not found a difference regarding speed. At least in my region.

To add to this, I used filezilla just to test out if the ftp had the same "feeling" as connecting via nautilus. It was the same. Also tried cute ftp from windows. All of which had the same speed. I even opened my FTP site from another friends place. Same thing.

If I had to recommend something, I would say to update your Ubuntu with the latest updates just in case. Maybe even ping your site and if you can ping another site to see any difference. If a big ping difference is found, you might try to use the other sites ftp just to test out the theory behind this. Basically a Trial and Error kind of thing.